# Angular 4 sample tutorial type script error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying out the tutorial given in the angular website. I hit a snag and I am not able to figure out the problem.

I created the project using angular cli.

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';



const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  selectedHero: Hero;
  heroes = HEROES;
  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> hero-detail.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
@Component({
selector: 'app-hero-detail',
templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
@Input() hero: Hero;
}
```

> hero.ts

```
export class Hero {
id: number;
name: string;
}
```

Src structure:

[image]

Getting the below TS error when launching the app

> Failed to compile.
>
> /Users/name/Documents/workspaces/angular-tutorial1/firstapp/src/app/hero-detail.component.ts
>   (3,12): Argument of type '{ selector: number; templateUrl: string; }'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.   Types of
>   property 'selector' are incompatible.
>       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: try to recompile ts files, paste js file of hero-detail.component

Comment: can you add your hero-detail.component.html file?

Comment: That's a weird bug giving `selector: 'app-hero-detail'` is definitely not a number. My guess is your cache isn't clean. Close your IDE, delete node_modules, `npm cache clean`, and `npm install` fresh is your best bet from here w/o more info. Other info needed would be the HTML where you have the `<app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>` and the hero-detail html itself

Comment: I restarted ng server and it worked. It seems like a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

app-component.html have a line like?

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```